# Summation of Binomial Coefficients Simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

The following equality is given by an online solver, but I would like to understand how the simplification is made:

$\binom{A+1}{B+1} = \sum_{i = h}^{h + A - B} \binom{i}{h} \binom{A-i}{B-h}$

So far I have tried to apply the [Chu-Vandermonde Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_Identity) and the property of [Summing
Binomial Coefficients over the Upper Index](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients_over_Upper_Index). How does one get from the summation to the simple binomial coefficient? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{A+1}{B+1}$ is clearly the number of $B+1$ sized subsets of an $A+1$ sized set.

Without loss of generality, let the $A+1$ sized set be the set $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,A\}$

Now... given a particular value of $h$ with $0\leq h<B+1$, let us count those subsets a different way by breaking into cases based on what the $(h+1)$'st largest value is in that subset.

If the $(h+1)$'st largest value in the subset happened to be $i$ then there are $h$ values yet to be selected from $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,i-1\}$ and there are still $B-h$ more values yet to be selected from $\{i+1,i+2,\dots,A\}$.  The values smaller can be selected in $\binom{i}{h}$ ways and the values larger can be selected in $\binom{A-i}{B-h}$ ways for a total of $\binom{i}{h}\binom{A-i}{B-h}$ different $B+1$ sized subsets of $\{0,1,2,\dots,A\}$ having $i$ as the $(h+1)$'st largest value.

Summing over all possible values of $i$, that is over all possible cases for the $(h+1)$'st largest value, gives the total number of $B+1$ sized subsets of $\{0,1,2,\dots,A\}$.

As both $\binom{A+1}{B+1}$ and $\sum\limits_{i=h}^{h+A-B}\binom{i}{h}\binom{A-i}{B-h}$ successfully count the same scenario (albeit in different ways), they must be equal.